# I Cant Launch LoadRunner 11.5

Tags: exception, loadrunner, hresult, launching

I'm having a problem launching the trial version of LoadRunner 11.5. It says:

> An unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click quit, the application will close immediately.
>   Retrieving the COM class factory component with CLSID 
>   {CF405F74-4814-AD81-525877D8C9A0} Failed due to the following 
>   error: 80040154 class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: Sounds like it's not installed properly.

Comment: Well I have tried installing multiple times Same error occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Which component is failing?  VUGEN? Controller? Analysis? Other?
2. Did this component ever work on this host?  If not, then this is an installation or rights issue
3. Have you contacted vendor support?  This assumes that you are under maintenance for your 11.5 version of LoadRunner.

Comment: Thanks for replying i had problem with VUGEN but it might be caused by another program  interaction i formatted PC and re installed it works fine now.